# Can not run unit tests through jest framework because of SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: angular, jestjs, angularfire2

I have problem with jest vs angularfire2. I set up jest and then I got error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`. Full output:

```
 PASS  src/app/diary/components/diary.spec.ts
 FAIL  src/app/diary/containers/my-dairy-page.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/node_modules/angularfire2/auth.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './auth/auth';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/containers/app.ts:18:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/core.module.ts:15:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.467s
```

#### Debug output

Output in debug mode so we can see full jest config:

```
sharikovvlad:ng2-diary-book svlad$ npm run jest -- --debug

> angular-ngrx-diary@0.0.0 jest /Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book
> jest "--debug"

{
  "config": {
    "automock": false,
    "browser": false,
    "cache": true,
    "cacheDirectory": "/var/folders/pf/510z0sc56zq3hvfb7lyr0jlr0000gn/T/jest_dx",
    "clearMocks": false,
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfigFile": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
      },
      "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
    },
    "haste": {
      "providesModuleNodeModules": []
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "js",
      "html",
      "json"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": [
      [
        "(.*)",
        "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/src/$1"
      ]
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
    "name": "520410dc90eed72792e9fd01593c2a6d",
    "resetMocks": false,
    "resetModules": false,
    "rootDir": "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book",
    "roots": [
      "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/src/setupJest.ts",
    "snapshotSerializers": [],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom",
    "testMatch": [],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|js)$",
    "testRunner": "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
    "testURL": "about:blank",
    "timers": "real",
    "transform": [
      [
        "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$",
        "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js"
      ]
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/node_modules/(?!@ngrx|angularfire2)"
    ]
  },
  "framework": "jasmine2",
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": false,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "expand": false,
    "mapCoverage": true,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "notify": false,
    "projects": [
      "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book"
    ],
    "rootDir": "/Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book",
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": null,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "20.0.4"
}
 PASS  src/app/diary/components/diary.spec.ts
 FAIL  src/app/diary/containers/my-dairy-page.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/svlad/dev/ng2-diary-book/node_modules/angularfire2/auth.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './auth/auth';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/containers/app.ts:18:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/core.module.ts:15:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.709s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-ngrx-diary@0.0.0 jest: `jest "--debug"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-ngrx-diary@0.0.0 jest script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/svlad/.npm/_logs/2017-08-20T21_09_30_035Z-debug.log
sharikovvlad:ng2-diary-book svlad$
```

I should not get syntax error, since this code should be transpiled to the ES5 (since config says so). Why I get it?

Also strange thing is **even if I set `transformIgnorePatterns` to empty array which means *ignore nothing* I will get same error**.

#### Version info

**Angular:**
4.3.5

**Firebase:**
4.2.0

**AngularFire:**
4.0.0-rc0

**Other (e.g. Ionic/Cordova, Node, browser, operating system):**

```
sharikovvlad:~ svlad$ node -v
v8.3.0
sharikovvlad:~ svlad$ yarn --version
0.27.5
sharikovvlad:~ svlad$ macosVersion
10.12.6
```

#### How to reproduce these conditions

**Steps to set up and reproduce**

1. Install jest with: yarn add --dev jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest
2. Add file `<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts` with contents: `import 'jest-preset-angular';`
3. Add jest block to the package.json:

> ```
>  "jest": {
>     "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
>     "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
>     "transformIgnorePatterns": [
>       "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ngrx|angularfire2)"
>     ]
>   },
> ```

But actually you can just:

1. Clone my repo https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/tree/feature/try-add-jest and checkout branch *try-add-jest*
2. Run *yarn install*
3. Run *npm run jest*
4. Here is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core problem is that ts-jest (jest-preset-angular is based on ts-jest) does not transpile JS files.

So I need something to do that work. Jest provides `babel-jest` transpiler out of the box. So I need to configure jest so he will transpile both js and ts files.

Here is my final jest configuraiton (package.json):

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|html)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(@ngrx|angularfire2))"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsConfigFile": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "useBabelrc": true
    },
    "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true
  }
},
```